# What is DEFINE in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, comments, ksh

Could anyone tell me the use of keyword DEFINE in KornShell (ksh) script? I searched over internet so enough but did not get a satisfactory solution.

**Example Script:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------‌​---------- 
#DEFINE TYPE=$PRODUCT_TYPE;
```

Comment: Which shell are you talking about?

Comment: Is there a chance that you're mistaking a `.c` or `.h` file to be a shell script?

Comment: You can paste in some example, if you are not sure what shell you talk about.

Comment: yes.. This is my example
DEFINE TYPE=$PRODUCT_TYPE;

Comment: That's not shell script.  We need to see more context.  Please edit the question to include an example with some more context (file name? other commands?  Just a few lines from the beginning should suffice).

Comment: #!/bin/ksh
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#DEFINE TYPE=$PRODUCT_TYPE;

Comment: @Vishal6589 Don't out code in comments.  Instead update your question.

Comment: If the `DEFINE` line is contained in the script as displayed above, then it's a comment.  Note that it's prefixed by `#`.  In shell `#` denotes a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#DEFINE` is a comment in this ksh script because it starts with a pound sigh (i.e., `#`):

**ksh Comments example:**

```
#Comments start with a pound sigh (i.e., #).
#This next line is a comment.
#DEFINE TYPE=$PRODUCT_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bourne shell and its POSIX derivatives and variants such as Bash and `ksh` do not have a `define` keyword (much less any uppercase keywords).

Perhaps you are looking at a script which contains a function by this name, or perhaps your system has a command with this name.  Or perhaps you are not looking at shell script at all -- for example, many SQL queries run SQL commands inside a snippet of shell script, but the SQL commands are obviously not shell commands.

Comment: How does that answer the question - if one could call this a question at all...?

Comment: Maybe it's a trick question?  It answers the question as I was able to interpret it.  "What do you use `define` for?" - "You don't."

Answer (score 1):

shell is KSH as specified in shebang (1st line of the script)

DEFINE does not exist in KSH but it is commented so i suspect that this line is used/generated by other process that can use this without affecting this script when run under KSH.